# Javascript - Max 4 Digits after Comma

Tags: javascript

I`m looking for a way to delete the last Digits from an Input with comma if the Value is more then 4.

Example:

Value : 13,314556 should be -> 13,3145.

Is there a way to just remove everything then the last 4 digits of this number with something like this?

```
     let value = 13,314556
        let result= value.split(',')[1].trim();
        if(result.length > 4){
          ...
        }
```

Comment: Is `value` supposed to be a string? as it stands it's a number with value `314556` (comma `,` is not the same as a decimal point `.` )

Comment: hey, the value is not supposted to be a string, it should be a number ( float )

Comment: It should be `let value = 13.314556` - no comma!

Answer (score 3):

### toFixed()

You can call `toFixed()` to format the number to a number of decimal places.

See [MDN Documentation for toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Modified from the example given in the above documentation:

```js
function myFormat(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(4);
}

// expected output: "13.3146" because of rounding
console.log(myFormat(13.314556));

// expected output: "0.0040"
console.log(myFormat(0.004));

// expected output: "123000.0000"
console.log(myFormat('1.23e+5'));
```

If you don't want rounding, simply be more precise and clip the end of the resulting string.

```js
    function myFormat(x) {
      return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(6).replace(/\d\d$/, '');
    }

    // expected output: "13.3145", will not do rounding
    console.log(myFormat(13.314556));
```

If you are working with currency or do similar important calculations, consider working with a library like [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/).

Answer (score 2):

alternative is to multiply by 10000, floor it, then divide by 10000.

```js
let value = 13.314556;
value=Math.floor(value*10000)/10000;
console.log(value)
```

or if you want to control the number of digits programmatically you could use something like this:

```js
let value = 13.314556;
value=Math.floor(value*Math.pow(10, 4))/Math.pow(10, 4);
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and
[join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods

Slice for slicing the string with the length you want

Join to re-create the number as you wish

---

### Edit

I added check if comma is in the number and also a parameter with the desired length

```js
function splitNumber(num, nbAfterComa) {

  const number = num.toString()
  if(!number.includes('.')){
    return number
  }
  const splitedValue = number.split('.')
  splitedValue[1] = splitedValue[1].trim().slice(0, nbAfterComa);
  return nbAfterComa > 0 ? splitedValue.join(',') : splitedValue[0]
}

console.log(splitNumber(13.314556, 4))
console.log(splitNumber(13.3, 4))
console.log(splitNumber(13.314556, 1))
console.log(splitNumber(13.314556, 0))
console.log(splitNumber(13, 8))
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the fast answer :) -> how I deal with this if i need a number and not a string? actually i cant do it with a string .. can i just parse the string into a number / float again?

Comment: You can use the `toString()` method and splice with the `.` instead of the comma. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.

```js
let value = "13,314556"
let result= value.split(',')[1].trim();
if(result.length > 4){
  console.log(result.split('').slice(0,4).join(''))
}
```

Comment: I think he is looking for `13,3145` not only `3145`